# Matplotlib AGG Backend Axis Labels Display Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

Afternoon,

MatplotLib is providing unreadable axis labels when using the AGG backend on a non-screen "web-app", same code on a device with screen (a windows laptop) produces expected results.

Using backend.use('agg') as specified here:
https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#howto-webapp

Same code produces two different outputs:

1. Unexpected - As it appears on my Ubuntu Django Webapp. Axes are clearly rendering text over each other without proper spacing being applied. Data appears to be organized differently. Plot is quite different looking.

[Ubuntu 16.04 - Without Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RtXC.png)

2. Expected - Single display as it appears on a windows 10 machine (laptop). Axes appear with correct spacing, no mudling of text, as expected graph/plot.

[Windows 10 - With Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9muL.png)

Relevant Code (The entire code is about 4kb, the plotting part for the above graph is here)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#...other code that processes data and whatnot...

#Active Sessions Collasped Graph
axes = plt.gca()
for dp in device.sessionStats:
    plt.plot([x.curTime for x in dp.sessions if x.name == "active"],[x.value for x in dp.sessions if x.name == "active"],label=dp.dataplane+" Active Sessions")
handles, labels = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
axes.legend()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig(graphDirectory+'dpActiveSessionsGraph.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Comment: A suggestion: Setting up Jupyter Notebooks, which is kind of like a browser-based IDE for python, is an excellent way to develop and debug matplotlib visualizations that you later want to deploy in a web app. For the investment of a few hours to learn Jupyter, you'll save days of webapp debugging time.

Comment: Very interesting, did not think about the similarities of the jupyter notebooks and the webapp deploy. Good suggestion, ill look into this as an option for debugging further.